# Updating webpage from background thread using socket.io but without event trigger?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask, socket.io

In almost every single example I've found of Flask/Socket.io, Socket.io triggers an event which is then processed by the Flask app, and dealt whatever response.

I need to consistently push new data to the page, without having an event trigger. In the Flask/Socket.io [online tutorial](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), they briefly mention this, but I'm sort of stuck.

As of now, I'm only pushing up data on client connects, making a new thread for every connection. Here is my code for that:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    # need visibility of the global thread objects
    print "We're working"
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

if not thread.isAlive():
    print "Starting Thread"
    thread = RandomThread()
    thread.start()
```

And then:

```
class RandomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 6
        super(RandomThread, self).__init__()

        ## Find Tweets every X amount of seconds
        def tweetFinder(self):
        print "Finding Tweets..."

        while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
            twit = Twitter()
            twit.login()
            cityName = twit.getUserTweets()
            print cityName
            socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': cityName}, namespace='/test')
            sleep(self.delay)

    def run(self):
        self.tweetFinder()
```

But how do I get this thread/process of pushing up data started right when the application is launched? I just want it working as an ongoing, infinite task in the backend, updating the page regardless of events.

Here is what the Flask/Socket-io docs say, I just can't figure out how to make it work the way I want it to.

> In all the examples shown until this point the server responds to an event sent by the client. But for some applications, the server needs to be the originator of a message. This can be useful to send notifications to clients of events that originated in the server, for example in a background thread. The socketio.send() and socketio.emit() methods can be used to broadcast to all connected clients:

```
def some_function():
    socketio.emit('some event', {'data': 42})
```

> Note that in this usage there is no client context, so broadcast=True is assumed and does not need to be specified.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Is your only problem that you want to start the background thread before a client connects? If yes, then why don't you start the thread right before calling `socketio.run()`?

Comment: I did something very similar based on an example I was directed to on github. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443676/how-do-i-stream-data-through-a-flask-application/41461533#41461533. My example is receiving data from a ZeroMQ thread but you could just as easily generate data in that background thread instead.